# XPath valid in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: xpath, google-chrome-devtools, robotframework, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to find a menu element via XPath in the JupyterLab UI; The following is an extract of the list of elements in the menu I am interested in, and should be a good minimal example of my problem:

```
<li tabindex="0" aria-disabled="true" role="menuitem" class="lm-Menu-item p-Menu-item lm-mod-disabled p-mod-disabled lm-mod-hidden p-mod-hidden" data-type="command" data-command="filemenu:logout">
    <div class="f1vya9e0 lm-Menu-itemIcon p-Menu-itemIcon jp-Icon"></div>
    <div class="lm-Menu-itemLabel p-Menu-itemLabel">Log Out</div>
    <div class="lm-Menu-itemShortcut p-Menu-itemShortcut"></div>
    <div class="lm-Menu-itemSubmenuIcon p-Menu-itemSubmenuIcon"></div>
</li>

<li tabindex="0" role="menuitem" class="lm-Menu-item p-Menu-item" data-type="command" data-command="hub:logout"><div class="f1vya9e0 lm-Menu-itemIcon p-Menu-itemIcon jp-Icon">
     <div class="f1vya9e0 lm-Menu-itemIcon p-Menu-itemIcon jp-Icon"></div>
     <div class="lm-Menu-itemLabel p-Menu-itemLabel">Log Out</div>
     <div class="lm-Menu-itemShortcut p-Menu-itemShortcut"></div>
     <div class="lm-Menu-itemSubmenuIcon p-Menu-itemSubmenuIcon"></div>
</li>
```

As you can see, both `<li>` items contain a `<div>` with the text `Log Out`, which is my main problem, as I am trying to write a general Xpath expression that can work for any Menu item. What I am currently trying to use is:

`//div[contains(@class, 'p-Menu-itemLabel')][text() = '${item}']`

Where ${item} can be any menu item, as all `<li>` items will have a similar div with text in them. The problem arises with the Log Out item, which is the only one that is repeated twice. In order to handle this special case, I have though of using

`//div[contains(@class, 'p-Menu-itemLabel')][text() = 'Log Out']/..[not(contains(@class,'p-mod-hidden'))]`

Since either one of the two `<li>` items will not contain that specific class (i.e., the currently active Log Out element).

This XPath works fine in Firefox and finds the element I am looking for everytime, however Chrome complains that it is not a valid XPath expression. Somehow this reduced version:

`//div[contains(@class, 'p-Menu-itemLabel')][text() = 'Log Out']/..`

works in Chrome, but any time I try to use an attribute selector on the parent element (i.e. `/..[something]`) it fails to recognize it as a valid XPath.

Does anyone have any idea of why? And what can I do to make Chrome recognize it as a valid XPath?

Comment: try substituting `parent::*` for `..`?

Comment: or `../self::*` for `..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Chrome doesn't like applying a predicate directly from the `..` parent axis.

But you can modify to use the long form: `parent::*`

```
//div[contains(@class, 'p-Menu-itemLabel')][text() = 'Log Out']/parent::*[not(contains(@class,'p-mod-hidden'))]
```

Or apply the `self::*` axis and then apply the predicate:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'p-Menu-itemLabel')][text() = 'Log Out']/../self::*[not(contains(@class,'p-mod-hidden'))]
```